# How to set certain True elements to False in a boolean array in python?

Tags: python

I have two boolean arrays `a` and `b`. The number of `True` elements in `a` is equal to the length of the array `b`, like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype='bool')
b = np.array([1,1,0], dtype='bool')
```

I know that I can use `np.where(a)[0]` to find the indices of `True` elements in `a`:

```
idx = np.where(a)[0]
```

And I have `idx`:

```
array([1, 3, 7])
```

Now according to `b`

```
array([1, 1, 0])
```

I want to keep the first two `True` values in `a` to be `True`, and flip the last `True` value to `False`. That is to say, to flip the value of `a[7]` to `0` and keep the rest of values in `a`:

```
res = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

How to do it in a python way? Suppose I have a long array of `a` and a relative short `b`. The `False` values in `b` are not necessarily to be the last one, could happen anywhere and multiple times, so `b` could also be

```
b = np.array([0,1,0], dtype='bool')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `b` to select the indices that needs to be set to `False`.

```
a[idx[~b]] = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Use negative indexing with `np.where`:

```
a[np.where(a)[0][-1]]=0
```

Your array as integer values:

```
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```